# Power series expansion of a product of two power series representations

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

#### Attempt:

Write $\dfrac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} = \dfrac{ a_0 b_n + a_1 b_{n-1} + ... + a_nb_0 }{a_0b_{n+1} + a_1 b_n + ... + a_{n+1} b_0} $

I can see this approach may seem a little laborious. I was trying to compute $\lim c_n/c_{n+1}$ and show that this is $R$ or at least $\leq R$. Any hints?

As for the secont part,notice that

$$ f(z) g(z) = (a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + .... )(b_0 + b_1 z + b_2 z^2 + ... ) = a_0b_0 + (a_0 b_1 + b_0 a_1 + a_0b_0 ) z + ... $$

So, it is clear that eventually $c_n$ will have the same representation that is given. Now, how do I make this argument formal? I mean it seems obvious...

Comment: Binomial theorem. Possibly applied to the partial sum.

Comment: It seems obvious because you're assuming what you want to prove. The idea of this exercise is to show that (1) the term by term product of power series is valid, and (2) if those power series represent functions then this term by term product represents the product of those functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Mertens Theorem if the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n\rightarrow x$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\rightarrow y$ and the latter series converges absolutely, then their Cauchy product $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_ky_{n-k}\rightarrow xy$$. Applying this to the power series' $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ you can conclude that the radius of convergence is at least $R$.

For a proof of Mertens theorem see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens.27_theorem

Let $f(z)$ be the Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ about $0$ and $g(z)$ be the Taylor series expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$ about $0$. Both have radius of convergence $1$ but their product is the constant power series $1$ and hence has radius of convergence $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks!! Why do you have 1 reputation? I dont get it!

Comment: @James something funny happened. One of my friends opened an account and, I don't know why, upvoted all my posts one by one. Hence a sudden inflation of reputation raised doubt in moderators' minds and they suspended me for using another account to inflate my reputation and deleted my friend's account and therefore I lost 220 reputation points! Now tell me is that fair? I'm a member for 3 years. Why should I suddenly use a made up account to inflate my reputation now? I already have enough reputation points of over 1500. This really offended me. But I'll not protest. I love this platform.